# Spark creating a new column based on a mapped value of an existing column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to map the values of one column in my dataframe to a new value and put it into a new column using a UDF, but I am unable to get the UDF to accept a parameter that isn't also a column. For example I have a dataframe  `dfOriginial` like this:

```
+-----------+-----+
|high_scores|count|
+-----------+-----+
|          9|    1|
|         21|    2|
|         23|    3|
|          7|    6|
+-----------+-----+
```

And I'm trying to get a sense of the bin the numeric value falls into, so I may construct a list of bins like this:

```
case class Bin(binMax:BigDecimal, binWidth:BigDecimal) {
    val binMin = binMax - binWidth

    // only one of the two evaluations can include an  "or=", otherwise a value could fit in 2 bins
    def fitsInBin(value: BigDecimal): Boolean = value > binMin && value <= binMax

    def rangeAsString(): String = {
        val sb = new StringBuilder()
        sb.append(trimDecimal(binMin)).append(" - ").append(trimDecimal(binMax))
        sb.toString()
    }
}
```

And then I want to transform my old dataframe like this to make `dfBin`:

```
+-----------+-----+---------+
|high_scores|count|bin_range|
+-----------+-----+---------+
|          9|    1| 0 - 10  |
|         21|    2| 20 - 30 |
|         23|    3| 20 - 30 |
|          7|    6| 0 - 10  |
+-----------+-----+---------+
```

So that I can ultimately get a count of the instances of the bins by calling `.groupBy("bin_range").count()`.

I am trying to generate `dfBin` by using the `withColumn` function with an UDF.

Here's the code with the UDF I am attempting to use:

```
val convertValueToBinRangeUDF = udf((value:String, binList:List[Bin]) => {
    val number = BigDecimal(value)
    val bin = binList.find( bin => bin.fitsInBin(number)).getOrElse(Bin(BigDecimal(0), BigDecimal(0)))
    bin.rangeAsString()
})

val binList = List(Bin(10, 10), Bin(20, 10), Bin(30, 10), Bin(40, 10), Bin(50, 10))

val dfBin = dfOriginal.withColumn("bin_range", convertValueToBinRangeUDF(col("high_scores"), binList))
```

But it's giving me a type mismatch:

```
Error:type mismatch;
 found   : List[Bin]
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
        val valueCountsWithBin = valuesCounts.withColumn(binRangeCol, convertValueToBinRangeUDF(col(columnName), binList))
```

Seeing the definition of an UDF makes me think it should handle the conversion fine, but it's clearly not, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that parameters to an `UDF` should all be of column type. One solution would be to convert `binList` into a column and pass it to the `UDF` similar to the current code.

However, it is simpler to adjust the `UDF` slightly and turn it into a `def`. In this way you can easily pass other non-column type data:

```
def convertValueToBinRangeUDF(binList: List[Bin]) = udf((value:String) => {
  val number = BigDecimal(value)
  val bin = binList.find( bin => bin.fitsInBin(number)).getOrElse(Bin(BigDecimal(0), BigDecimal(0)))
  bin.rangeAsString()
})
```

Usage:

```
val dfBin = valuesCounts.withColumn("bin_range", convertValueToBinRangeUDF(binList)($"columnName"))
```

Comment: That works, and just adding a comment, when calling this in the `withColumn` call, it'll have to be curried: `val dfBin = valuesCounts.withColumn("bin_range", convertValueToBinRangeUDF(binList)(valuesCounts.col(columnName)))`

Comment: @NateH06: Ah, yes, I forgot to mention that. I added your usage code to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this** -

```
scala> case class Bin(binMax:BigDecimal, binWidth:BigDecimal) {
     |     val binMin = binMax - binWidth
     |
     |     // only one of the two evaluations can include an  "or=", otherwise a value could fit in 2 bins
     |     def fitsInBin(value: BigDecimal): Boolean = value > binMin && value <= binMax
     |
     |    def rangeAsString(): String = {
     |       val sb = new StringBuilder()
     |       sb.append(binMin).append(" - ").append(binMax)
     |       sb.toString()
     |     }
     | }
defined class Bin


scala> val binList = List(Bin(10, 10), Bin(20, 10), Bin(30, 10), Bin(40, 10), Bin(50, 10))
binList: List[Bin] = List(Bin(10,10), Bin(20,10), Bin(30,10), Bin(40,10), Bin(50,10))


scala> spark.udf.register("convertValueToBinRangeUDF", (value: String) => {
     |     val number = BigDecimal(value)
     |     val bin = binList.find( bin => bin.fitsInBin(number)).getOrElse(Bin(BigDecimal(0), BigDecimal(0)))
     |     bin.rangeAsString()
     | })
res13: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,StringType,Some(List(StringType)))


//-- Testing with one record

scala> val dfOriginal = spark.sql(s""" select "9" as `high_scores`, "1" as count """)
dfOriginal: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [high_scores: string, count: string]


scala> dfOriginal.createOrReplaceTempView("dfOriginal")

scala> val dfBin = spark.sql(s"""  select high_scores, count, convertValueToBinRangeUDF(high_scores) as bin_range from dfOriginal """)
dfBin: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [high_scores: string, count: string ... 1 more field]

scala> dfBin.show(false)
+-----------+-----+---------+
|high_scores|count|bin_range|
+-----------+-----+---------+
|9          |1    |0 - 10   |
+-----------+-----+---------+
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: That's pretty good, but I should have specified, that binList is dynamic and needs to be passed in as a parameter to the UDF, rather than hard coded, which is what was getting me tripped up.

Comment: I edited my post. binList can be declared outside udf before registering udf. You can keep binList Dynamic this way. Additionally you can decide if you want to populate binList from some file or hive table to control range values from outside code.